# Como limitar o tamanho da área de texto em um formulário no Contact Form 7?

Tags: wordpress

Coloquei um formulário simples em meu site mas estou tendo dificuldades em limitar a área destinada as mensagens do usuário (aquela que dá pra redimensionar com o mouse), pois ela é tem um tamanho padrão que ultrapassa as margens da sessão. Não encontrei nenhuma opção de como fazer isso, alguém pode me dar uma ajuda? Obrigado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá @nos139 você pode tentar limitar a quantidade de caracteres neste formato:

`[textarea* your-message minlength:10 maxlength:140]
[count your-message]`

`[textarea* your-message minlength:10 maxlength:140]
[count your-message down]`

Ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

`count` de acordo com o que o usuário digitar chegou na contagem de 140 caracteres não será mais possível.

Ou se o caso for apenas de limitar mesmo o tamanho do campo tente seguir esta sintaxe

`[textarea your-message 40x10 "your message here ..."]`

Ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @nos139 disponha.